# Is something else than com and org used in java?

Tags: java, import

After reading the question [Java packages com and org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org) and answers, I am still curious:

1. Is there some strict rule that I can use only `com` `edu` and `org`?
2. And, is it bad idea to create package starting with something else than this?

Say, I am fro, Czech Republic and I own `PavelJanicek` company, can I create package which would be imported like

```
 import cz.paveljanicek.usable.awesomeutils;
```

**edit**: Since one of answers supposes it should be possible, can I apply it also to new domain TLDs?

example:

```
import berlin.berlincity.touristguide.api;
```

Comment: Yes you can, that's exactly how we determine package names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package name is defined by the language specification as a succession of [valid identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Identifier), separated by `.`.

So the convention (for unicity purposes) is to use your domain name but any valid identifier can be used. This is a valid package name too:

```
é.è.û.¥
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this link: [Java Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) and [Java Package namings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

You should also look at [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868619/java-package-naming-and-non-com-domains?rq=1)

At last a quote to add:

> > If you're just doing personal projects where nobody else will use the code, then you can make up a package name that you like. Don't
> >     make up something that starts with com. or net. or other top-level
> >     domain though, because that would imply that you own the domain name
> >     (ie. using com.john as your package name just because your name
> >     happens to be John is not a good idea).
>
> If you're going to give the code to anybody else, you should use a
>   globally unique package name, which according to Java conventions
>   means you should register and use a domain name.

Short: Use whatever you like :)

Comment: This answer references good information- if you take a look over the answering guidelines ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ) the community recommendation is to provide some context for links in case the site goes offline in future.

Comment: @HarmLezz Updated some parts

Answer (score 1):

You missed a lot of the information given in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org). Here once again a snipped of what [Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html) defined:

> The prefix of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase ASCII letters and should be one of the top-level domain names, currently com, edu, gov, mil, net, org, or one of the English two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard 3166, 1981.

Today we have even more top-level domains. The important part is to choose the domain you own in reverse order. I suggest you should read the answer once again, slowly. The goal is to avoid naming conflicts by choosing unique namespaces. And because domain names are already owned by a single company / person, they are good candidates to choose.

Comment: specifically out of curiosity: Do TLD names like 'ninja' or 'berlin' apply to the rule?

Comment: I would guess, YES. You may as well read the rules outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Answer (score 1):

yes, that's the way you have to do if you own paveljanicek.
there are a lot of 'com' and 'org', but you can find many others;
for example, logback logging library contains classes in package

```
ch.qos.logback....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want just honoring the Java limitations for identifiers.

Said that, usually is safe using Java conventions, but `killerapp.gui.Main` is a valid class identifier